# How to read appsettings.json with List of values?

Tags: c#, appsettings

I have the following appSettings.json file

```
  "UrlManagement": {
   "UrlList": [ 
   {
        "Microsoft":{
            "resource":"xyz",
             type": "iot"
        }, 

        "AWS":{
            "resource":"abc",
             "type": "storage"
        },     
   }]
  }
 }
```

I have class

```
public class UrlManagement
{
    public string CompanyName;
    public URLList UrlList;
}

public class URLList 
{
     public string Resource;
     public string Type;
}
```

I am trying to get these values as follow

```
  private List<string> GetConfigurationDictionary()
  {
        var items = this._configuration.GetSection("UrlManagement:UrlList:0").
            GetChildren().ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
  }
```

I am getting null values for x.Value

Comment: Can you try with return collection= this._configuration.GetSection("UrlManagement: UrlList").Get<UrlManagement>();

Comment: issue is not with return type. Once I get the values, I shall change the return type. Currently items is coming as NULL

Comment: Nope. I am mentioning the change in the way the GetSection is loaded as _configuration.GetSection("UrlManagement: UrlList").

Comment: you miss ``"`` for ``type`` key in json.

Comment: @Sajid That was the error while typing it in stack overflow.  corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could search the section`UrlManagement:UrlList:0`, like the following code :

```
private List<UrlManagement> GetConfigurationDictionary()
{
    List<UrlManagement> result = this._configuration
        .GetSection("UrlManagement:UrlList:0")
        .GetChildren()
        .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Get<UrlList>())
        .Select(x => new UrlManagement { CompanyName = x.Key, UrlList = x.Value })
        .ToList();

    return result;
}
```

**Demo**

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{item.CompanyName} ==> {item.UrlList.Type}:{item.UrlList.Resource}");
}
```

**Result**

```
AWS ==> storage:abc
Microsoft ==> iot:xyz
```

I hope this helps you fix the issue

Comment: I would like to have generic class, as tomorrow we might add "Google"

Comment: that is the structure of ``json`` :), i will search other solution to make it generic.

Comment: @kudlatiger: i have updated my answer, can you check it?

Comment: But it shall map to class UrlManagement, not UrlList

Comment: why?i think you need values of ``(type,resource)`` of all companies?

Comment: I also need to get companies. Please refer my class in question.  I am configuring almost 20 companies in app settings. List<UrlManagement> will be my final collection.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211555/discussion-between-kudlatiger-and-sajid).